# How to calculate daily average from aggregate results with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on outputting some data and I want to pull the daily average of some numbers.

[image: Data Sample]

As you can see, what I want to do is count the amount of rows received/results(think the row ID) and then divide it against the day value to make the daily average.(30/1) , (64/2) etc I've tried everything, but I keep running into a wall with this.

As it stands, I'm guessing to make this work a sub query of some sort is needed. I just don't know how to get the day(Row id 1,2,3,4 etc) to use for the division.

```
SELECT calendar_date, SUM(NY_dayscore * cAttendance) 
FROM  vw_Appointments 
WHERE status = 'Confirmed'
Group by calendar_date
```

Attempted count with distinct, to no avail

```
SUM(NY_dayscore * cAttendance) ) / count(distinct calendar_date)
```

My original code is long and cba to post it all. So just attempting to post a small sample code to get guidance on the issue.

Comment: Fix your sample data because they don't match with your explanations.

Comment: And what happens when Day X has no rows? Like a holiday, a weekend day, a disaster recovery day, etc.

Comment: I have to agree, your sample data and expected results don't match. `60/3 = 20` not `10`. But, what does your actual data look like? Provide us with representative sample data, along with the expected results you're after. I *suspect* that window functions and `ROWS BETWEEN` would work here, but you've tagged SQL Server 2008 (and `ROWS BETWEEN` was introduced in SQL Server 2012). SQL Server 2008 is almost entirely out of support so is that really the version you're using?

Comment: @Larnu , Yeah made a mistake typing this up. 60/3 = 20. , editing the op with better sample data. I am unfortunately using Sql Server 2008

Comment: I supposed `NY_dayscore * cAttendance` yields `showed`, and `calendar_date` means `date`, don't they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would use the cumulative average:

```
select calendar_date, sum(NY_dayscore * cAttendance),
       avg(sum(NY_dayscore * cAttendance)) over (order by calendar_date) as running_average
from vw_appointments a
where status = 'Confirmed'
group by calendar_date
order by calendar_date;
```

In SQL Server 2008, this is more difficult:

```
with a as (
      select calendar_date, sum(NY_dayscore * cAttendance) as showed
      from vw_appointments a
      where status = 'Confirmed'
      group by calendar_date
     )
select a.*, a2.running_average
from a outer apply
     (select avg(showed) as running_average
      from a a2
      where a2.calendar_date <= a.calendar_date
     ) a2
order by calendar_date;
```

Comment: Wow I think this is it, Thank you! Didn't know about Cross and Outer apply. There's so much to learn :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `sum(showed) over (..)/row_number() over (..)`

```
WITH Table1(date, showed) AS
(
 SELECT '2019-01-02', 30 UNION ALL
 SELECT '2019-01-03', 34 UNION ALL
 SELECT '2019-01-03', 41 UNION ALL
 SELECT '2019-01-04', 48
)
SELECT date, 
       sum(showed) over (order by date) / 
       row_number() over (order by date)
       as daily_average
 FROM Table1
GROUP BY showed, date;

date        daily_average
2019-01-02  30
2019-01-03  52
2019-01-03  35
2019-01-04  38
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/CRJZ12422)</kbd>

Comment: Yes  the multiplication yields showed, and calendar_date means date   

   
Tried your method, but getting a "Incorrect syntax near order" error when executing 
    SELECT calendar_date, SUM(ShowedUp) OVER (ORDER BY calendar_date) AS rowid
 From vw_Appointments

Comment: @JohnW hm, OK, you got the error, because your version is 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Is it `ROW_NUMBER()` that you are missing?

```
SELECT 
  calendar_date, 
  SUM(NY_dayscore * cAttendance) / (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY calendar_date ASC)) AS average
FROM  vw_Appointments 
WHERE status = 'Confirmed'
GROUP BY calendar_date
ORDER BY calendar_date
```